# ApnsPHP Error: 'Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Class file 'PATH/' doesn't exists ''

Tags: php, ios, codeigniter, push-notification, apns-php

I'm using the ApnsPHP library with Codeigniter to send notifications push for iOS. Now, I'm a little desperate here with the next error:

```
[Mon Jun 15 16:22:59.480063 2015] [:error] [pid 1820] [client 192.168.1.139:4707] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Class file '/var/www/html/kids_book/application/models/CI/Exceptions.php' does not exists' in /var/www/html/kids_book/application/models/ApnsPHP/Autoload.php:20\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: ApnsPHP_Autoload('CI_Exceptions')\n#1 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('CI_Exceptions')\n#2 /var/www/html/kids_book/system/core/Common.php(143): class_exists('CI_Exceptions')\n#3 /var/www/html/kids_book/system/core/Common.php(481): load_class('Exceptions', 'core')\n#4 /var/www/html/kids_book/application/views/notificacion/add_notificacion.php(102): _exception_handler(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/var/www/html/k...', 102, Array)\n#5 /var/www/html/kids_book/system/core/Loader.php(833): include('/var/www/html/k...')\n#6 /var/www/html/kids_book/system/core/Loader.php(419): CI_Loader->_ci_load(Array)\n#7 /var/www/html/kids_book/application/controllers/notificacion.php(117): CI_Loader->view('notificacion/ad...', Array)\n#8 [internal function]: Notificacion->add_notificacion()\n#9 /v in /var/www/html/kids_book/application/models/ApnsPHP/Autoload.php on line 20, referer: http://192.168.1.132/kids_book/index.php/notificacion/add_notificacion
```

This error appears in the moment I add the notification in my DB, and the library try to send the push notification to the device. Honestly, I have no idea why is this happening. I'll appreciate any help here. Thanks in advance.

Model:

```
class Push_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

public function push_notificacion_ios($keys) {

    $count = count($keys);

    date_default_timezone_set("America/Caracas");


    require_once 'application/models/ApnsPHP/Autoload.php';

    $push = new ApnsPHP_Push(
            ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX, "application/models/notificacionesPUSH.pem"
    );

    $push->connect();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $message = new ApnsPHP_Message($keys[$i]);

        $message->setBadge(1);

        $message->setText('Tiene una nueva notificación de Kids Book');

        $message->setSound();

        $message->setCustomProperty('key', 1);

        $message->setExpiry(30);

        $push->add($message);
    }
    $push->send();

    $push->disconnect();
}
```

PD: Sorry for my awful English, not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

in `config.php` file

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session','your_librery_name');
```

You can learn on [ellislab](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) tutorial as well

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I understand this point, but I'm actually loading my library in the model where I'm calling the class. I'll edit my post and give you the model.